# Jenkins missing build history but not stage view after migration

Tags: jenkins

moving + upgrading Jenkins to new server (2.401.3) by copying everything from JENKINS_HOME.  However, "Build History" is empty but not "Stage View".  I am still able to click/access/read old builds from "Stage View".  Any pointers what I have done wrong?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try clicking the arrow icon to right of 'trend' to actually try render the "Build History" in the jenkins UI panel. Downward arrow represents list shown, upward means list hidden like in your screenshot.
Hovering over the cloud icon to left of 'Build History' should reveal status as well.